# Separate files or one file for classes/methods

Tags: python, pygame, libraries, file-format, code-structure

I am writing a game in Python that has many classes and methods, and I want to know if it is advantageous to store the classes in the main python .py file or store each category of classes in separate files, then import them. This would help with organization, but are there any other pros/cons?

Comment: The result of import is essentially making the compiler jump to that file and parse it in place of the import line. So essentially, it's helpful with organization and sanity.

Comment: thanks @Byte56! can youphrase that as a full answer?

Comment: Well, the question is kind of off topic for gamedev. I can send it over to stackoverflow for you and provide an answer there. How's that?

Comment: thanks @Byte56! now i have to wait for an answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that the result of import is essentially making the compiler jump to that file and parse it in place of the import line. Basically making it like the entire file was pasted into the file doing the importing, at the line where the import happens.

So essentially, it's helpful with organization and sanity. Once a project starts to get large enough, it would be impractical to maintain all the code in a single file.

Comment: :D thanks. i knew how it worked, but didnt realize that i could use it like this!

Comment: I don't think this is true. If it were we should be able to access variables between files without importing as long as there is one file that imports all.